# How to make conditions in a laravel query, based on returned value of a helper function

Tags: laravel, eloquent, model

I'm using Laravel 5.7. I have a 'Match' model whose first participant name is returned from a helper function getFirstParticipant(Match $match).
I am trying to get certain matches from DB whose first participants are e.g. 'John'. Is it possible that I use Eloquent query functions to do so for example something like this?

```
Match::where('firstParticipant', 'John')
```

or any other solutions?

I am copying my helper function below if it can help to declare the problem:

```
function getFirstParticipant(Match $match)
    {
        $structure_id = $match->structure_id;
        $seed = $match->matchResult->first_seed;

        $placement = Placement::where('structure_id', $structure_id)->where('seed', $seed)->first();

        return !empty($placement->player_id) ? $placement->player->username : $placement->team->name;
    }
```

Comment: have you tried that?

Comment: This is not possible. Because where function only accepts a column name as its first argument. @lagbox

Comment: well there is no way to know anything about your setup since you have provided no information about it

Comment: What is a first participant? How do you get it? Is it another model?

Comment: no it is gotten from a helper function and it is not a column of matches table. there are intermediate models. first participant can not extract easily. it can be a team name or username or user full name or ... . So it is extracted from a helper function based on the situations. @IGP

Comment: Can't you edit your question and post the helper function?

Comment: I added the helper function in the question @IGP

Answer (score 0):

Just sub a variable into the second parameter.

```
$first = getFirstParticipant(Match $match);

Match::where('firstParticipant', $first->first_name)->get();
```

Obviously I'm assuming some variable names here such as first_name. But you should be able to follow that. Just use your helper to return a model value and insert that returned value as the second parameter of the where argument.

Comment: firstParticipant is not a column of matches table. It is extracted from a helper function based on the situations and can be a team name or username or user full name or ... .

Comment: oh, but didn't you say in your comment above that you're aware that the "where" only accepts column names as its first argument?

Comment: Sorry, but my intention in that comment (answer to lagbox who asked if I tested where function) was that 'where' is not helpful, because first participant is not a column @maximus1127

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way. Database design issues aside, the only way I can see this working is by using `collection` methods.

```php
Match::get()->filter(function ($match) {
    return $match->firstParticipant == 'John'; // Or is it getFirstParticipant($match) ?
})->all();
```

```php
# Laravel 6.x introduces LazyCollections
Match::cursor()->filter(function ($match) {
    return $match->firstParticipant == 'John'; // Or is it getFirstParticipant($match) ?
})->all();
```